# Parsing and intereacting between two json in Python

Tags: python, json

I need your help with the following task.
I have the following json object as input file

```
{"source": {        
    "datatype": "panorama",     
    "project": "Test project",
    "zoomlevel": 19,        
    "imageids": [14295321, 14295325, 14295332, 14295303, 14295301]      
}}
```

Then I have second JSON list of objects

```
{
"ProjectId": "0dd1fc70-dc0d-433e-b301-00988c483240",
"SuperProjectId": 1,
"ProjectedSRID": 0,
"Name": " Test project ",
"Owner": "<Owner>",
"MetadataStandard": 2,
"Description": null  },
{
"ProjectId": "ec4a0fb9-1b8e-41a9-9fa5-01909127c261",
"SuperProjectId": 1,
"ProjectedSRID": 0,
"Name": " Test project 2",
"Owner": null,
"MetadataStandard": 2,
"Description": null},
{
"ProjectId": "cc651d6a-be26-4b5a-8938-039573a361b5",
"SuperProjectId": 1,
"ProjectedSRID": 0,
"Name": " Test project 3",
"Owner": null,
"MetadataStandard": 2,
"Description": null
}
]
```

From the first JSON I need to take ‘project’ I do this like this:

```
with open ('input_json.json', 'r') as f:
input = json.load(f)
project_name = input['source']['project']
```

I need to loop the second JSON and take the ‘ProjectId’ value from the object where ‘Name’ value is equal to ‘project’ value from the first JSON. I don't have any idea on how to do this. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````
    "datatype": "panorama",     
    "project": "Test project",
    "zoomlevel": 19,        
    "imageids": [14295321, 14295325, 14295332, 14295303, 14295301]      
}}'''

json_array='''[{
"ProjectId": "0dd1fc70-dc0d-433e-b301-00988c483240",
"SuperProjectId": 1,
"ProjectedSRID": 0,
"Name": " Test project ",
"Owner": "<Owner>",
"MetadataStandard": 2,
"Description": null  },
{
"ProjectId": "ec4a0fb9-1b8e-41a9-9fa5-01909127c261",
"SuperProjectId": 1,
"ProjectedSRID": 0,
"Name": " Test project 2",
"Owner": null,
"MetadataStandard": 2,
"Description": null},
{
"ProjectId": "cc651d6a-be26-4b5a-8938-039573a361b5",
"SuperProjectId": 1,
"ProjectedSRID": 0,
"Name": " Test project 3",
"Owner": null,
"MetadataStandard": 2,
"Description": null
}]
'''
from json import loads
input = loads(json)
project_name = input['source']['project']
project_name = project_name.strip()
array=loads(json_array)


for item in array:
    if item['Name'].strip() == project_name:
        print(item['ProjectId'])```
````